# Error changing cast HashMap to Map

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am new in Spring MVC and wanted to see if I can get little suggestion here. When I change from HashMap to Map, I see error. Thank you for any suggestion.

```
FROM:
HashMap<String, Object> schoolTeacherMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) teachersService.allSchoolTeachersget();
 TO:    
Map<String, Object> schoolTeacherMap = (Map<String, Object>) teachersService.allSchoolTeachersget();
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message

Comment: These are the three suggestions I see in red mark. It says: Multiple markers at this line:  1. Map cannot be resolved to a type 2.Type safety: unchecked cast from  Map<String, Object> to Map<String, Object> & 3. Map cannot be result to a type.

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace by editing the question instead of mentioning it in the comment.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments are shown initially. Put everything in one place (the question) so that it's easy to read. Make it easy to help you.

Comment: Do you `import java.util.Map;`?

Comment: You should change the title from "changing" to "changing cast from"

Comment: This should work.  In Java 8+, both casts are redundant. Without seeing the specific error you're encountering we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I figured it out.I changed to

```
Map<String, Object> schoolTeacherMap =
```

and left right side as it is, it worked.